# Avoid duplicates of adding xml files in BaseX

Tags: xml, basex

I am trying to use BaseX to manage my xml files. I have created a database and added xml files using the Data Properties tab and inputting a directory that points to my xml files. That works well
   However, when I add a new set of xml files in the directory and go to Database Properties and click Add, it adds the new xml files to the database but also create duplicates of the existing xml files. Is there a way to prevent this? Or do I have manually add succeeding files individually rather than just point it to the directory?
   I hope I am making sense here. Please help.

Bryan

Comment: I don't think so, not from the the GUI. When you click Add you are effectively running the [ADD](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#ADD) command. This adds all files on the path specified into the database, the duplicates arise because duplicate paths for resources are allowed in the database. Your options are to use the REPLACE command, write XQuery to compare the list of files in directory to the resource paths in the database and add only the new ones or move files once they're added.

Comment: ok thank you for the clarification